# Orders of magnitude and differentials

Tags: calculus

I have an expression on the form
$$
v\cdot \nabla(vv)
$$
where $v$ is a vector. According to my lecture notes, the above expression is $\mathcal O(v^3)$, but is this necessarily true when we take the derivative?

Please note that $v$ is a velocity vector, so I can assume it to be a well-behaved function.

Comment: How do you define $vv$? Please make every notation clear for generals.

Comment: Presumably $vv = \langle v,v \rangle$, especially since it is a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I'll answer for records. If we take the derivative:

$\vec{v} \cdot \vec\nabla (v^2)$

$2v (\vec{v} \cdot \vec\nabla v)$

So with the chain rule it's easier to see that the statement is still $\mathcal O(v^3)$